# Shopify order status not clear

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I am using shopify admin REST API to fetch status of orders created by customers and admin but there is no single status to check, it has financial status, fulfillment status and sometimes shipping status. An order can be fulfilled if financial status is still pending. Also a restocked item is still showing up as fulfilled. All this is very confusing. I need simple order status like:

1. created
2. paid
3. processing
4. fulfilled
5. shipped
6. delivered
7. return in progress
8. returned
   how to map shopify order status with above statuses?

Answer (score -1):

All your needs are available to you in three very interesting and very available endpoints that have to do with orders. Namely **refunds**, **transactions** and **fulfillments**. When you download orders with some status filtering, you are being very simplistic and general. Shopify will deliver to goods, but for your purposes of discovering the deeper status, it is up to you to examine those other aspects for the true picture.

Once you get used to this, you'll find it is dead simple to figure out the exact status of an order, and therefore you can deal with whatever you have to deal with.